# How to get all points inside a polygon in openlayers 4.x?

Tags: javascript, geometry, openlayers

I want to integrate a feature using Openlayers 4.x is that I want to get all points inside a polygon on map. Currently I can get all coordinates of polygon itself.

But I want all coordinates or points inside of the polygon. If I explain it more that means I want all points or coordinates on the map surrounded by the polygon area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on @willsters answer, if having identified the candidates and you are only looking for points (where the geometry is the extent) forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent could then be used in the reverse direction to see if the points intersect the polygon's geometry.

```
var candidates = [];
source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(myPolygon.getGeometry().getExtent(),function(feature){
    if (feature.getGeometry().get('type') == 'Point') {
        candidates.push(feature);
    }
});

var selected = [];
candidates.forEach(function(candidate){
    source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(candidate.getGeometry().getExtent(),function(feature){
        if (feature === myPolygon) {
            selected.push(candidate);
        }
    });
});
```

Also for single coordinate points I think it could be done in a single step:

```
var selected = [];
source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(myPolygon.getGeometry().getExtent(),function(feature){
    if (feature.getGeometry().get('type') == 'Point' &&
        myPolygon.getGeometry().intersectsCoordinate(feature.getGeometry().get('coordinates')) {
            candidates.push(selected);
    }
});
```

Regarding dividing into cells something like this would generate pinpush points for each cell of a 10x10 grid which contained the polygon.  If only part of a cell intersected the polygon a pinpush at the center of the cell might be outside the geometry.

```
var extent = myPolygon.getGeometry().getExtent();
for (var i=extent[0]; i<extent[2]; i+=(extent[2]-extent[0])/10) {
    for (var j=extent[1]; j<extent[3]; j+=(extent[3]-extent[1])/10) {
        var cellExtent = [i,j,i+(extent[2]-extent[0])/10),j+(extent[3]-extent[1])/10];
        source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(cellExtent,function(feature){
            if (feature === myPolygon) {
               var pinPush = new ol.feature(new ol.geom.Point(ol.extent.getCenter(cellExtent)));
               source.addFeature(pinPush); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply. Basically I want to draw a point grid or you can say I want to divide the area inside polygon as rows and columns so that each cell contain a pushpin. Do you have any idea how to do in openlayers 4.x. I think your sample of code is near to my requirement. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Mike, I have a confusion about source on this line : source.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent() because I have openlayers map and only a polygon on the map. So in this case what is the source? and it seems that your nested loops doesn't work properly, getting some error. Could you please add your code on jsfiddle.

Comment: `source` is the source used for the vector layer containing the polygon i.e. `layer.getSource()`   It wasn't intended to be a working example and there were two typing errors which I have now corrected.

Comment: I am getting this error now cellExtent.getCenter is not a function

Comment: Hi @Mike, thanks for your help. I have another question, if I want to change the rows and columns like 5X4 or anything like 3X4... then where I need change around the code?

Comment: If the grid is x wide and y high the width increment becomes `(extent[2]-extent[0])/x` and height increment is `(extent[3]-extent[1])/y`

Comment: cool, can you do another favor to me. If I want to create grid instead of marker icon inside polygon, then how to sort this out? Is it possible to create grid inside the polygon in openlayers? It could be square grid etc.

Comment: You could easily replace each pinpush with something covering its entire grid cell `gridPush = new ol.feature(ol.geom.Polygon.fromExtent(cellExtent))`;  But some of those might be only partly inside your polygon.

Comment: thank you very much for your such a great help to me, I am really grateful to you. I am facing a problem. I am trying to draw polygon on grave fields, some graves are vertically and some are horizontally. Pushpins are working fine for horizontal graves but for vertical graves pushpins are showing in different direction. If graves are in north to south but pushpins draws in different direction in different angle. Is it possible to change this direction of all pushpins?

Comment: It would be best to start a new question for that, including the code you are using and screenshots showing the problem.

Comment: Hi @Mike, this is the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783646/how-to-change-maker-icons-direction-in-openlayers?noredirect=1#comment92494557_52783646

Comment: instead of polygon if I want to generate pins on a linestring in openlayers with column numbers specified, which code I need to modify on your row columns code?

Answer (score 3):

I often include the turf.js library alongside of openlayers specifically for tasks like this. Most of my geometries are nativley in geojson so turf.js is a perfect fit. If you have a geojson FeatureCollection. you can iterate the .features array (or even just any array of `[x, y]` points) and check each one to see if it's inside your polygon. I can make a working fiddle if it helps.

```js
// In this example I'm looking for all features
// that have AT LEAST ONE point within  
// the world extent (WGS84)
const polygon = turf.bboxPolygon([-180, -90, 180, 90])
myGeoJson.features.forEach(function(feature){
    const points = turf.explode(feature);
    const pointsWithin = turf.pointsWithinPolygon(points, polygon);
    if(pointsWithin.features && pointsWithin.features.length){
        // feature has AT LEAST ONE point inside the polygon
        // I can see what points by iterating the
        // pointsWithin.features array
    }else{
        // feature has ZERO points inside the polgyon
    }
});
```

http://turfjs.org/docs#pointsWithinPolygon

Answer (score 1):

Use `vectorSource.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent()` with `polygonGeom.getExtent()`. That will get you the extent shortcut for most of them. After that you will need to either implement point-in-poly yourself (there are numerous sources online for this) or use a library like https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts. OpenLayers only provides geometry intersection with extents.